# How can I format my harddrive in FreeDOS?

Tags: hard-drive, format, freedos

I zero'd  out my hard drive with something called kill disk. It unfortunately doesn't have a format option. So now my hard drive is basically 20GB of unallocated space. When I boot from my USB (which has kill disk on it) and then I exit kill disk, I see a DOS prompt.

This is FreeDOS, and has a limited set of executables. However, I can load executables onto my USB and then they will be available for me to use on the freedos prompt.

Question: What executable(s) should I put on this USB so that I can run them and eventually format my hard drive so it is usable again?

Comment: Check your bios (if you can get into it).  Some have a primitive format option.

Answer (score 1):

If you're planing on installing another OS, most OS disks have built in disk management, including partitioning and formating.

Unless you just want to set up a partition and leave it as is, I'd simply use the OS disk.

Answer (score 0):

Can you boot a CD on the system? Try gParted, it's very good.
i'm sure you can boot it from USB as well.

Does that help you in your situation?

Answer (score 0):

You may use any Windows OS disk to format your hard disk, you can also create partitions

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you edit your post and explain what means `use any Windows OS disk to format your hard disk`. It is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

FDISK is what you need to do http://home.mnet-online.de/willybilly/fdhelp-internet/en/hhstndrd/base/fdisk.htm but why not just use a bootable modern OS, which will see and make use of your hard drive? Most PC's ship with Windows OS so all you need is to make a flash drive with that OS. https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10  Even if your computer did not use Windows it can probably work fine "unactivated" with a watermark on the display. With luck or if your have a Windows sticker and license key, you can use it to activate, or digital license will be found and auto-activate your PC.
Mint Linux or Ubuntu are also good free OS choices for a novice.